# checksum with different string returns the same output

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anybody explain why this statement returns the same output?

```
SELECT CHECKSUM('2019-03-14 00:15:32')
SELECT CHECKSUM('2019-03-13 00:15:42')
```

output:

```
843611027
```

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: sql server management studio

Comment: they are different for me: `1667848105` and `-479645778` - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4fde6cd2af5a51732b29e5ef72bdc6b3

Comment: [consider using HASHBYTES instead. With a specified MD5 hash algorithm, the probability that HASHBYTES will return the same result, for two different inputs, is much lower compared to CHECKSUM.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: They're the same because 4 + 3 = 3 + 4, and your database default collation is one where that particular result is obtained (you can get a collision with a different value, for example, if you explicitly add `COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2` to the strings, but doubtless there are others). In other words: yes, `CHECKSUM` is quite bad when it comes to not colliding. It's a horribly naive function with some special exceptions in it that make collisions even more likely than just summing the values does.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch, that's probably a function of collation. I get identical values on SQL Server 2017 with Latin1_General_BIN.

Comment: @EricBrandt - Yes using `Latin1_General_BIN` or `Latin1_General_BIN2` gives the same output for me too. So looks like the collation is the reason. Would be interesting which collation is used on the question (`SELECT CONVERT (varchar, SERVERPROPERTY('collation'))`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> If at least one of the values in the expression list changes, the list checksum will probably change. However, this is not guaranteed. Therefore, to detect whether values have changed, we recommend use of CHECKSUM only if your application can tolerate an occasional missed change. Otherwise, consider using HASHBYTES instead. With a specified MD5 hash algorithm, the probability that HASHBYTES will return the same result, for two different inputs, is much lower compared to CHECKSUM.

You've hit a collision. Have a look at [`Hashbytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to answer this specifically, but more generally in terms of the utility of a checksum process.

There are a few different checksum algorithms, of varying quality.  The most basic checksums (like the one you're showing) are very fast to run, but have a high collision rate (the likelihood that two different strings will have the same output).

If you need to be very confident of a low collision rate, use a "cryptographically secure" checksum algorithm, which has been mathematically proven to have a very low collision rate.  A good example is SHA256.

Basic checksums are good for error detection (i.e. did the machine read a credit card number or barcode correctly) but not for tampering detection (i.e. did someone mess with this important message) or identification (is this the right password).